# MultiValueDictKeyError - Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I am having a problem by getting MultiValueDictKeyError in Django. I am trying to logout user from my website so I made the following codes.

In html

```html
    </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-3">
              <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}" class="nav-link">
              <i class="fas.fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout 
              </a>
              <form action="{% url 'logout'%}" method="POST" id="logout">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden">
              </form>
            </li>
```

Here's my login and logout function in say 'accounts/views.py'

```
    def login(request):
    # request method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Saving the username and password in a variable
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        #checking if the user name and password matches using auth function
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # checking if the user is found in Database with user name and password, if found then login
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Welcome to BTRE.")
            return redirect('dashboard')
        # if user name and password do not match with DB. display message and redirect to login page.
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Incorect Username and/or Password. Please type correct user name and password")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render (request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
        messages.success(request,"You are now logged out")
        return redirect('index')
```

> > Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout
>
> Django Version: 3.0.2 Python Version: 3.8.1 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'django.contrib.humanize',  'pages.apps.PagesConfig', 
>   'listings.apps.ListingsConfig',  'realtors.apps.RealtorsConfig', 
>   'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\DD\Desktop\btre\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py",
>   line 76, in **getitem**
>       list_ = super().**getitem**(key)
>
> During handling of the above exception ('username'), another exception
>   occurred:   File
>   "C:\Users\DD\Desktop\btre\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\DD\Desktop\btre\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 115, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\DD\Desktop\btre\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 113, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\DD\Desktop\btre\accounts\views.py", line 12, in login
>       username = request.POST['username']   File "C:\Users\DD\Desktop\btre\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py",
>   line 78, in **getitem**
>       raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
>
> Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/logout Exception
>   Value: 'username'

Comment: Sorry. spelled Django wrong in title. :)

Comment: you can edit your post to change the spelling. Change request.POST['username'] to request.POST.get(username') and for password also.

Comment: #Saving the username and password in a variable
        username = request.POST.get ('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

Comment: nop. not working. still not logging out the user and redirects to login page and showing error 'ERROR: Incorrect Username and/or Password. Please type correct user name and password". which i made in login function

Comment: I think the issue is in html.

Comment: please include the traceback

Comment: what i see that the javascript (getElementbyId) is looking to post 'logout' request. where 'logout' function is already defined in views.py. However, It just redirects me to login page and showing me error 'Incorrect Username and/or Password (i.e. login function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name ='login'),
    path('logout', views.login, name ='logout'),
    path('register', views.register, name ='register'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard , name = 'dashboard')
]
```

sorry guys for wasting your time. one little error in urls.py causes me a headache for three hours. I appreciate your time guys. Again apologize for wasting your time.